# python: multiple inheritance and __add__() in base class

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I've got a base class where I want to handle `__add__()` and want to support when `__add__`ing two subclass instances - that is have the methods of both subclasses in the resulting instance.

```
import copy

class Base(dict):
    def __init__(self, **data):
        self.update(data)

    def __add__(self, other):
        result = copy.deepcopy(self)
        result.update(other)
        # how do I now join the methods?
        return result

class A(Base):
    def a(self):
        print "test a"

class B(Base):
    def b(self):
        print "test b"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(a=1, b=2)
    b = B(c=1)
    c = a + b
    c.b() # should work
    c.a() # should work
```

**Edit**: To be more specific: I've got a class `Hosts` that holds a `dict(host01=.., host02=..)` (hence the subclassing of `dict`) - this offers some base methods such as `run_ssh_commmand_on_all_hosts()`

Now I've got a subclass `HostsLoadbalancer` that holds some special methods such as `drain()`, and I've got a class `HostsNagios` that holds some nagios-specific methods.

What I'm doing then, is something like:

```
nagios_hosts = nagios.gethosts()
lb_hosts = loadbalancer.gethosts()
hosts = nagios_hosts + lb_hosts
hosts.run_ssh_command_on_all_hosts('uname')
hosts.drain() # method of HostsLoadbalancer - drains just the loadbalancer-hosts
hosts.acknoledge_downtime() # method of NagiosHosts - does this just for the nagios hosts, is overlapping
```

What is the best solution for this problem?

I think I can somehow "copy all methods" - like this:
    for x in dir(other):
        setattr(self, x, getattr(other, x))

Am I on the right track? Or should I use Abstract Base Classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is a bad idea. You're trying to inject methods into a type. That being said, you can certainly do this in python, but you'll have to realize that you want to create a new type each time you do this. Here's an example:

```
import copy

class Base(dict):
    global_class_cache = {}

    def __init__(self, **data):
        self.local_data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        new_instance = self._new_type((type(self), type(other)))()
        new_instance.update(copy.deepcopy(self).__dict__)
        new_instance.update(copy.deepcopy(other).__dict__)
        return new_instance

    def _new_type(self, parents):
        parents = tuple(parents)
        if parents not in Base.global_class_cache:
            name = '_'.join(cls.__name__ for cls in parents)
            Base.global_class_cache[parents] = type(name, parents, {})
        return Base.global_class_cache[parents]

class A(Base):
    def a(self):
        print "test a"

class B(Base):
    def b(self):
        print "test b"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(a=1, b=2)
    b = B(c=1)
    c = a + b
    c.b() # should work
    c.a() # should work
    print c.__class__.__name__
```

**UPDATE**
I've updated the example to remove manually moving the methods -- we're using mixins here.

Comment: nice, didn't know about `type('A_B', (A, B), {})` works - that looks very much what I looked for - internally we're still discussing if my general approach is correct though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer your question without more information. If `Base` is supposed to be a common interface to all classes, then you could use simple inheritance to implement the common behavior while preserving the methods of the subclasses. For instance, imagine that you need a Base class where all the objects have a `say_hola()` method, but subclasses can have arbitrary additional methods in addition to `say_hola()`:

```
class Base(object):
   def say_hola(self):
     print "hola"

class C1(Base):
   def add(self, a, b):
      return a+b

class C2(Base):
   def say_bonjour(self):
      return 'bon jour'
```

This way all instances of `C1` and `C2` have `say_hola()` in addition to their specific methods.

A more general pattern is to create a `Mixin`. From Wikipedia:

> In object-oriented programming
>   languages, a mixin is a class that
>   provides a certain functionality to be
>   inherited by a subclass, while not
>   meant for instantiation (the
>   generation of objects of that class).
>   Inheriting from a mixin is not a form
>   of specialization but is rather a
>   means of collecting functionality. A
>   class may inherit most or all of its
>   functionality from one or more mixins
>   through multiple inheritance.